# Is it possible to bypass queuing disciplines in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking

To provide a little context, I have used netem to delay packets on the TX side from an application (let's say DHCP). For some reason, I'm unable to observe it. So, I'm curious if it is bypassing queuing discipline altogether ?

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you capture the traffic and see that?

Comment: Capture traffic, at what level you mean ? I have used wireshark, which showed no delay. If you are suggesting something else, let me know.

Comment: Possibly at app layer and transport. could you share the commands trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! if you are using a `class` based traffic shaping and policing and don't setup an appropriate `filter` and a `default` `class` is given.

Please provide more info on the exact commands you are using to setup traffic shaping/policing so that we can help you precisely.